# Adding UITextField to UIToolbar does not work

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I am trying to add a UITextField to UIToolbar on my UINavigationView but it does not appear on the toolbar. The code is very simple. Here's what it looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 32)];
    UIBarButtonItem *textFieldItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:textField];
    self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: textFieldItem, nil];

}
```

I tried adding other toolbarItems instead, and they all work. For example, the following code works with no problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(openCamera:)];
    self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: buttonItem, nil];

}

- (void)openCamera:(NSString *)str
{
   // some code..
}
```

This is the only change I've made to a default generated single view application and I have no idea why it's not working. By the way I am on iOS7. Anyone have an idea what's going on? Thank you!

Comment: The code looks ok, try running on iOS 6 to be sure and consider raising a bug report. Add some other button items at the same time and see how they're laid out.

Comment: I tried running on iOS6.1 simulator and it still doesn't work. I guess it's not iOS version issue after all. Also when I add them at the same time, only the rest of the toolbarItems show up. The textField does not.

Answer (score 2):

The `borderStyle` property of `UITextField` is set to `UITextBorderStyleNone` by default. That might be why it doesn't appear to be visible. Try this:

```
urlField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

On another note, when my view doesn't show up as expected, I usually try to display its border to help me figure out if it's actually on the screen.

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor magentaColor] CGColor];
```